# How to get MSSQL to work with WAMP?

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I have tried everything I can possibly think of to get MSSQL to work with WAMP. Here is my code

```
<?php
$database = "appas";
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=(IP) ; Database = $database", "sa1", "Password02");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 1 );

$query = 'select * from user';

// simple query
$stmt = $conn->query( $query );
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
   print_r( $row['first'] ."\n" );
}

echo "\n........ query for a column ............\n";

// query for one column
$stmt = $conn->query( $query, PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1 );
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ){
   echo "$row\n";
}

echo "\n........ query with a new class ............\n";
$query = 'select * from user order by last';
// query with a class
class cc {
   function __construct( $arg ) {
      echo "$arg";
   }

   function __toString() {
      return $this->DepartmentID . "; " . $this->Name . "; " . $this->GroupName;
   }
}

$stmt = $conn->query( $query, PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'cc', array( "arg1 " ));

while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ){
   echo "$row\n";
}

echo "\n........ query into an existing class ............\n";
$c_obj = new cc( '' );
$stmt = $conn->query( $query, PDO::FETCH_INTO, $c_obj );
while ( $stmt->fetch() ){
   echo "$c_obj\n";
}

$stmt = null;
?>
```

I am getting this error

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\wamp\www\Register\configdb.php on line 3
( ! ) PDOException: could not find driver in C:\wamp\www\Register\configdb.php on line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  255760  {main}( )   ..\configdb.php:0
2   0.0004  256608  __construct ( ) ..\configdb.php:3
```

I have no idea why it is not finding the driver - I have the DLL installed i think. I really am grasping at straws here if anyone knows my problem or could link a proper installation guide for MSSQL in WAMP 2.5 that would be fantastic.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDvUn.jpg

Comment: sql server is on your local system?

Comment: its external but im not going to put the address here

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754357%28v=sql.105%29.aspx have you installed all the drivers ?

Comment: Make sure the sql server is on and you can run queries in the phpmyadmin

Comment: im trying to use a MSSQL server not mysql @Joshua Byer

Comment: ive tried using that but its mssql 2005 not 2014 @arlind

Comment: doing the scripts on that page i get the error could not find driver1 @Arlind

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the database from your machine in some other way? For example, I expect MSSQL has a client app you can use to connect to it.

Comment: You definitely don't have the driver for MSSQL. [Did you check this repository by any chance?](https://github.com/azure/msphpsql)

Comment: Do any of you have a copy of php with mssql enabled that i could mirror